# How to get a File via a Servlet, avoiding unnecessary GETs?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-headers, browser-cache

I had some files in my webapp in a simple folder in the WAR file. The requests were very fast: as soon as the browser cached a file, it did not request the file contents again until the file changed.

Now I put the files in a different location, and implemented a servlet to deliver the files. The code is simple, but the performance drops. This is the minimal example:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>File</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.FileServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>File</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/file/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

FileServlet

```
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
        Path path = fs.getPath("/some/folder/", req.getPathInfo());
        Files.copy(path, resp.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

How can I improve it, so that I get the same performance as, for instance, tomcat's `DefaultServlet`?

Comment: so just forget the `Files.copy()` method, and just try to buffer and send data.

Comment: Check the implementation of `DefaultServlet`: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.java

Comment: I also suggest you do not response the file with servlet, just give the direct link like the before, and for setting some extra header data, give some hand of servlet `Filter`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The class is quite big... what's the key point here? Supporting `HEAD` requests and setting `Last-Modified`? Evaluating `If-Unmodified-Since`? Is it necessary / helpful to support byte ranges?

Comment: @noise It all depends on your requirement. I was just posting it so you can compare what you are doing in the base case with what Tomcat does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Last-modified" header can be helpfull, please look section "Cache on the client" here:

http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index2.html